# Apache POIでExcelのセルに対して均等割り付けをする方法がわからない

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

**環境**

- Apache POI 4.1.1
- JDK 11.0.5
- Excel 2016

**やりたいこと**
Apache POIを用いてExcelファイルを作る際に均等割りを行いたい

イメージ図
[image: 結合したセルに対して均等割り付けを行う]

***試したこと***
ライブラリに存在する均等割り付けと思われるスタイルを適用して実行

```
    // 対象セルに均等割りを適用
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
　　style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
　　style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
　　row.getCell(cellNumber).setCellStyle(style);
```

参考にしたページ
http://www.moriwaki.net/wiki/index.php?%5B%5BPOI%5D%5D

試した結果
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上記画像のように均等割り付けが適用できていない

**質問**
poiを用いて均等割り付けを行う方法に関して教えていただきたいです

Comment: `justifyStyle`なんて識別子が突然現れていますが、これは`style`との書き間違えでしょうか?

Comment: 失礼しましたこちらstyleの書き間違えです　修正いたしました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の様にすることで均等割りを実現しました。ありがとうございました。

```
// 対象セルに均等割りを適用
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.DISTRIBUTED);
style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
row.getCell(cellNumber).setCellStyle(style);
```